# Lock icons won't go away

Tags: windows-7

While running a restore function of a backup program I had to stop it. After that I noticed that most (all?) icons on my desktop and inside folders show small locks. The backup software company didn't help. They say it's a coincidence.

It's been several months already, but all the old folders and files still show locks. I checked  the obvious file ownership settings. Everything looks normal. The account that I use has full rights and I'm able to manipulate the files, so the lock icons don't seem to indicate any restrictions, however they are still present.

Just to clarify, new files and folders don't have the locks.

Comment: Try resetting the Access Control List (ACL) permissions. From a command prompt, type the following commands: 1. `takeown /f "%userprofile%\Desktop" /r /d y >nul` 2. `icacls "%userprofile%\Desktop" /grant:r %username%:F /t /c /q`

Comment: I'm getting ERROR: The current logged on user does not have ownership privileges on
       the file (or folder) ".....".

Comment: Did you get that error after the first or the second command? Did you get just a single error or multiple ones? I guess the `"....."` is supposed to be the actual file/folder name?

Comment: Sorry for so few details. 1) the error appears after the first command. I ran it in a sub-directory as a test. This single error refers to a folder. Administrators has full access to this folder and I think my account is a member of the Administrators group.

Comment: Type `icacls "%userprofile%\Desktop"` and post the output of the command.

Comment: BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12983/discussion-between-user1566515-and-and31415)

Answer (score 0):

Found this as reference to run for likewise locks on folders and icons "missing user group" :

1. Right-click the folder or drive that has a lock icon and select
   "Properties".
2. Click on the "Security" tab, then select "Edit..."
   to change permissions. Click "Add.."
3. In the text field for "Object Name", enter in "Users" (without quotations). Hit "OK".
4. "Apply", "OK", and voila, the padlock next to the icons should be gone.

(via http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e8347f6f-e835-42e1-8509-eee38f83bb05/how-do-i-get-a-lock-icon-on-my-folder-to-come-off?forum=w7itprosecurity)

Comment: Wouldn't this allow all users to access all files in that folder?

Comment: Wouldnt that depend on the rights you set for users for that folder? e.g. "only read" ?

Comment: I think this would be a brute force approach. I know that I'm logged in as a member of the Administrators group with full control allowed. If Windows shows a lock on a folder, that implies that something else is wrong and needs fixing.

Comment: What is the difference in security settings (groups, rights) between a folder WITH a lock and a folder WITHOUT a lock icon?

Comment: That depends. Some "locked" folders have same security settings as "unlocked" folders. That's what's strange about it. Also, I'm logged in as the owner of the folders with all possible permissions. Could it be a Windows bug?

Comment: so the folders with the locks have the groups "authenticated users" and "Users"?

Comment: No, the folders with the groups "authenticated users" and "Users" don't have locks, but some unlocked folders don't have "authenticated users" or "Users".

Comment: So why don't you add these groups?

Comment: Because some unlocked folders don't have "authenticated users" or "Users". This implies that adding those groups is not necessary.